# Deploy a Rails app to Openshift: rhc - Username or password is not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, openshift

Our company wants to build a Rails-based backend website and we chose the OpenShift platform to host and deploy. To connect the two, all the guides lead to the installation of the ruby `rhc` gem and then setup it.

I'm fresh to OpenShift and I'm trying to setup the rhc toolkit on a remote Ubuntu server. Now I ran `gem install rhc` and everything went fine. Since I have to configure rhc through `rhc setup`, I ran this command afterwards and just after asking which server I want to use (I left it blank to use openshift.redhat.com) it comes to the login part.

At this moment, OpenShift Online allows you to login only with your GitHub account, so I gave in the GitHub credentials and... voilà! `Username or password is not correct`. Tried this both on PuTTy and ConEmu.
I swear I checked the login data more than 1000 times, and I'm totally lost.

Thank you a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use OpenShift Online NextGen Developer Preview, you do not use the `rhc` client. You need to use the `oc` client. So anything you read where it says `rhc` is the wrong documentation.

Once you are logged in through the new web console, select on the '?' in circle top right and select command line tools. It will give you links to the 'oc' tools to download, plus the command you need to run to login from the command line using a session access token.

The link to that page should be:

- https://console.preview.openshift.com/console/command-line

Also suggest you get down and use the free eBook for the new platform at:

- https://www.openshift.com/promotions/for-developers.html

It uses a VM, but ignore the client login step from that and use that from page above instead and then follow examples in the book against the Online NextGen Developer Preview instead.

Comment: First, many thanks Graham for your reply. I forgot actually the main point behind this problem and I updated my request accordingly. Now, since a Rails application is to accomplish, I've found no guide that makes use of the `oc` client, they all use `rhc`. Or is there a workaround maybe?

Comment: @gmlvsv For new questions unrelated to this, you should actually create a new question in SO.